# How to make two classes sharing a same attribute?

Tags: python

I have defined a class that posseses an attribute `score` which is a matrix.
Let's say that `var` is an instance of this class.

I have another class that needs to access one particular cell of the matrix `var.score`. I would like to do something like that :

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, r, c):
        self.cell = var.score[r][c]
    ...
    # Then make operations on self.cell
```

Except that if `self.cell` is modified, the modification should also reflect on `var.score[r][c]`. The goal of creating `self.cell` and not simply using `var.score[r][c]` is for clarity and for avoiding dragging `r` and `c` along the following definition of the class.

I've seen solutions using wrapper mutable objects like a list that didn't satisfied me. So what is the best solution to implement that ?

Comment: The title is IMHO misleading. You talk about only one class in your question. Anser to your title would probably be inheritance...

Comment: Nop, I'm talking of two distinct classes. First paragraph : "I have defined a class...", second paragraph : "I have _another_ class..."

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that. It does make more sense now. I just pictured something completely different when I read it(and that's my problem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a property:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, r, c):
        self.r = r
        self.c = c

    @property
    def cell(self):
        return var[self.r][self.c]

    @cell.setter
    def cell(self, val):
        var[self.r][self.c] = val
```

Then:

```
>>> var = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> x = Foo(0, 1)
>>> x.cell
2
>>> x.cell = 8
>>> var
[[1, 8], [3, 4]]
>>> y = Foo(1, 1)
>>> y.cell = 88
>>> var
[[1, 8], [3, 88]]
>>> var[0][1] = "Hello"
>>> x.cell
'Hello'
```

Comment: Gah, beat me to it :P.

Answer (score 1):

@BrenBarn solution is correct. Just a suggestion, you shouldn't use global variable var like that. `var` should be passed to the class in the initialization.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, r, c, var):
        self.r = r
        self.c = c
        self.var = var

    @property
        def cell(self):
        return self.var[self.r][self.c]

    @cell.setter
    def cell(self, val):
        self.var[self.r][self.c] = val
```

If you want to keep it same for the entire class, declaring class variable would be equally accurate.

Comment: Oh please, don't tell me that you don't like global variables because you are afraid of them. Man, this is Python, not C! And I hope you're not stupid to forget how you  named what. In this particular case, I don't see why shouldn't he use global variable. In fact, here it may be even desirable to use it.

Comment: With due respect, the concepts of CS remains the same if you are using Python, ruby or even Java. Global variables are fine, as long as you don't mutate them. It would be stupid to think, that just because you are using python you are free to do anything.

Comment: I am always free to do whatever I want to do, regardless the language and/or machine.
Nobody can put me into a box sayin stupid things like: "you have to use debugger" or "global variables are bad, don't use them because you'll make a bug" or "don't inherit this or that"
nor any other idiotic thing that accumulated through years because there is flood of programmers that don't know where their bottom stops and head begins.

Comment: Because of "Programmers" like you python is not as respected in the programming world as it is deserves to be. Python gives you lot of power, but with great power comes great responsibility. There is different between being open-minded and bull-headed. There are lit of stuff of static languages that don't make sense in dynamic languages, hatred for mutating global variables is not one of them. Besides there is no "have to", you can use global variables but it is not advisable to mutate them. Remember on thing python gives you freedom to do mostly everything, but assumes you aren't an idiot.

Comment: I see it daily on SO. Clever people asking how to do simple things because they were put into a box and lost their creativity just because of these superstitions enforced to help those who don't really know what they're doing. These clever people usually receive the answer they would implement without asking. You're limited only with yourself, real limitations that HW or language are suffering off, and, yeah, if you are nice man, some conventions. These "do this", "don't do this" aren't even for children.

Comment: Ok bro I guess we should agree to disagree, and stop wasting each other time

Comment: In fact, Python is more popular because of me. :D But I am responsible only for my code, code that I'll share follow even those hated "rules", or explains why they aren't followed in particular cases. Python gives you power only when you want it to. If you use Python to print few lines of text, where's power there. So, responsibility comes when you write powerful program. Or else, use bash or batch. Yuck the syntax! And, yeah! I love Python because of power! Dynamic is my lifestyle.

Comment: You're obviously the cleverer :D We may agree that we disagree, but grab the power, when it's offered, don't stick to standards. I discovered as very yung that they are breaking and slowing down my progress. So I shook them off.

Comment: I'm also guilty ofre this, ,I also crave power. There are lot of times when i end up using powerful constructs like metaclasses and descriptors when o don't need to. Don't be dogmatic about anything but one should know how much of something is good